# Почему воспроизводится видео в другом табе когда я нахожусь в другом

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ребят Помогите разобраться , есть два таба (первый, второй) видео находится во втором табе, когда я захожу на сайт автоматически открывается первый таб и сразу воспроизводится видео во втором табе и звук выходит. Как сделать так чтобы только при клике на второй таб начало автоматически воспроизводится видео ?

```
<div class="notebook2">
        <input type="radio" name="notebook2a" id="notebook2a_1" checked="checked">
        <input type="radio" name="notebook2a" id="notebook2a_2">
    <div id="slider">
        <label for="notebook2a_1" style="margin-top:6px;">Gallery</label>
                <div class="left_arrow">
                    <img src="full/left_arrow.png" id="left_arrow"/>
                </div>
                <div class="right_arrow">
                    <img src="full/right_arrow.png" id="right_arrow"/>
                </div>
                <img src="full/1.png" id="mainImage" class="mainImage"/>
<div id="video">
            <label for="notebook2a_2" style="margin-top:7px;">Video</label>
            <video class="videocontent" preload autoplay controls src="full/ps.mp4"></video>
        </div>
 #video{
    width:580px;
}
.videocontent{
        width:580px;
        height: 380px;
        margin-top: 45px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из [документации](http://htmlbook.ru/html/video/autoplay) про `autoplay`:

> При наличии этого атрибута видео начинает воспроизводиться автоматически после загрузки страницы

Чтобы видео не проигровылось при загрузке страницы уберите этот атрибут и добавьте ID для удобства.

```
<video class="videocontent" id='myVid' preload controls src="full/ps.mp4"></video>
```

и повесьте атрибут `onclick="document.getElementById("myVid").play()"` на нужный таб

чтобы остановить видео - `onclick="document.getElementById("myVid").pause()"` на нужный таб.

Comment: Сделал получилось , но теперь при клике на первый таб видео не останавливается , а продолжает воспроизводится

Comment: @Влад обновил ответ

Comment: спасибо ))))))) !